# How to deploy WAR on JBoss-5.1.0.GA using cargo-maven plugin and wait till it gets deployed before running Integration Tests?

Tags: web-services, integration-testing, maven-3, maven-cargo, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a maven web application(Spring+ApacheCXF webservices) and have a couple of IntegrationTests(*IT.java). I want to run integration tests using failsafe plugin by deploying the war file using cargo-maven plugin.

Here is my pom configuration:

```xml
<plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <container>
            <containerId>jboss51x</containerId>
            <home>C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA</home>
            <append>false</append>
            <log>${project.build.directory}/logs/jboss51x.log</log>
            <output>${project.build.directory}/logs/jboss51x.out</output>
            <timeout>300000</timeout>
          </container>
          <configuration>
            <type>existing</type>
            <home>C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default</home>
            <properties>
              <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
              <cargo.jboss.configuration>default</cargo.jboss.configuration>
              <cargo.rmi.port>1099</cargo.rmi.port>
              <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
            </properties>
            <deployables>             
              <deployable>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>admin-services</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>                
              </deployable>
            </deployables>
          </configuration>
        </configuration>
         <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>start-container</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deployer-deploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>stop-container</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deployer-undeploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>            
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>failsafe-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
</plugin>
```

But the problem is cargo plugin deploys the WAR file and immediately failsafe plugin is trying to execute the IntegrationTests, and by that time application is not deployed so tests are failing.

With the same configuration I am able to run the integration tests in two steps successfully.
1. execute cargo:deployer-deploy
2. execute integration-test

Is there anyway to trigger failsafe plugin only after the application got deployed by cargo plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `pingURL` parameter to provide an url to verify the deployment is completed: see http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide

Using cargo you dont have to deploy the application, there is also support for: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Functional+testing (but that depends on your tests of course)